# Generative Model for learning Periodic solutions 3-body/N-body problems

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, gan, generative-models, mathematics

I am tasked with finding research where a GAN or any other generative model is used to generate new shapes of 3-bodies moving under the influence of each others' gravitational pull, in a periodic motion, for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-body_problem#/media/File:Three_body_problem_figure-8_orbit_animation.gif): with the 3-bodies going about in that 8-shaped orbit. My findings tell me that, this is a "**Periodic solution** for a **3-body problem** ", and I learned that there are a finite number of these solutions out there. I also learned that a **restricted 3-body problem** might have more periodic solutions per se. I am not too sure about the authenticity of that claim in the previous line.

I was wondering if one could make a generative/GAN-like model make it learn the distribution of these shapes, and thereby generate more and more of these shapes? If so, has there been research on this already? If yes, could someone point me to it, since I am unable to do so myself, coming from a pure Machine Learning-Software Development background, not having much idea of the terms like Lagrangians and the Eulerian and so on?

P.s. 3-body is just for reference, I don't mind hearing about anything similar on the N-body problem front as well.

Any and every ideas/questions/intuition are appreciated. :-)

Comment: By shapes i mean 1- time period of the periodic motion of all the three-bodies.